# Python return list of duplicates in list in order

Tags: python, list, duplicates, set, repeat

How do you quickly return a list of duplicates for a list in the order that they appear? For example `duplicates([2,3,5,5,5,6,6,3]) results in [5,6,3]` meaning that the repeated element is only added to the resulting duplicates list when its second element appears. So far I have the code below but its not running fast enough to pass large test cases. Is there any faster option without imports?

```
def duplicates(L):
    first = set()
    second = []
    for i in L:
        if i in first and i not in second:
            second.append(i)
            continue
        if i not in first and i not in second:
            first.add(i)
            continue
    return second
```

Comment: The whole point of this is for *you to solve the problem*.  I'll give you a hint: the thing that is slowing you down is checking if something is `in second` list... indeed, it sort of makes your `first` set pointless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're doing well in using a set `first` since it has a O(1) time complexity for the `in` operation.
But in the other hand you're using a list for `second`, wich turns this function into a O(N^2) and, in the worst case, you're going through the `second` list twice.

So, my sugestion to you is using a dictionary to store the numbers you found.

For exemple:

```
def duplicates(L):
    first = dict()
    second=[]
    for i in L:
        if i not in first:      #First time the number appears
            first[i] = False
        elif not first[i]:      #Number not on the second list
            second.append(i)
            first[i]=True

return second
```

Note that I used a Boolean for the dictionary key value to represent whether the number appears more than 1 time or not (or if it was already added to de `second` list).
This solution has O(N) time complexity wich means that is way faster.

Answer (score -1):

Revision of posted code

- Use a dictionary rather than a list for 'second' in OP code.
- List Dicts have O(1) rather than O(n) look up times
- Dicts keep track of order of insertion for Python 3.6+ or could use OrderedDict

**Code**

```
def duplicatesnew(L):
    first = set()
    second = {}   # Change to dictionary
    for i in L:
        if i in first and i not in second:
            second[i] = None
            continue
        if i not in first and i not in second:
            first.add(i)
            continue

    return list(second.keys())  # report list of keys

    lst = [2,3,5,5,5,6,6,3]
```

**Performance**

*Summary*

- Comparable on short lists
- 2X faster on longer lists

**Tests**

> Use lists of length N
>
> For N = 6: use original list
>
> N > 6 use:

```
lst = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(N)]
```

1. N = 6

   Original: 2.24 us
   Revised:      2.74 us
2. 1000 random numbers between 1 and 10

   Original:  241 us
   Revised:       146 us
3. N = 100, 000

   Original: 27.2 ms
   Revised:  13.4 ms